# Converting ASP script to TSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert this to a stored procedure in SQL Server from an ASP script. I have tried to follow the procedures outlined at http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html, but due to lack of understanding; I can't figure out what is needed to create the search string.  Once I can figure that out, then I can attach the string to the rest of the dynamic sql. I have the list to table function, and the intList_tabletype defined in the database, as well as the rest of the SP. The searchArr variable can be one keyword, a delimited list of keywords or a phrase. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
           'SQL - Keywords
            If Len(strSearch) > 0 Then

                'Create array of keywords. If we're doing a PHRase 
                'search, an array with only one position is created 
                'containing the entire search string. If an AND or 
                'an OR "keyword" search is being performed, each word 
                'is put into it's own array position.
                If strSearchType = "PHR" Then
                    searchArr(0) = Trim(strSearch)
                Else
                    searchArr = strSearch.Split(" "c)
                End If

                'Keyword search SQL
                tmpSQL1 = "(Brewery.BreweryName LIKE "
                tmpSQL2 = "(Products.description LIKE "
                tmpSQL3 = "(Products.Notes LIKE "
                tmpSQL4 = "(Products.SKU LIKE "
                For i = 0 To UBound(searchArr)
                    If i = UBound(searchArr) Then
                        tmpSQL1 = tmpSQL1 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%')"
                        tmpSQL2 = tmpSQL2 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%')"
                        tmpSQL3 = tmpSQL3 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%')"
                        tmpSQL4 = tmpSQL4 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%')"
                    Else
                        tmpSQL1 = tmpSQL1 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%' " & strSearchType & " Brewery.BreweryName      LIKE "
                        tmpSQL2 = tmpSQL2 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%' " & strSearchType & " Products.description     LIKE "
                        tmpSQL3 = tmpSQL3 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%' " & strSearchType & " Products.Notes           LIKE "
                        tmpSQL4 = tmpSQL4 & "'%" & searchArr(i) & "%' " & strSearchType & " Products.SKU             LIKE "
                    End If
                Next

                'Put it all together
                searchSQL = searchSQL & "AND (" & tmpSQL1 & " OR " & tmpSQL2 & " OR " & tmpSQL3 & " OR " & tmpSQL4 & ") "

            End If
```

When i run this script on the web page, I get this string.

Single keyword Or Phrase

```
AND ((Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '%Bud%') OR (Products.description LIKE '%Bud%') OR (Products.Notes LIKE '%Bud%') OR (Products.SKU LIKE '%Bud%') OR (Brands.Brand LIKE '%Bud%'))
```

Multiple Keywords

```
AND ((Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '%Bud%' OR Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '%Busch%') OR (Products.description LIKE '%Bud%' OR Products.description  LIKE '%Busch%') OR (Products.Notes LIKE '%Bud%' OR Products.Notes LIKE '%Busch%') OR (Products.SKU LIKE '%Bud%' OR Products.SKU LIKE '%Busch%') OR (Brands.Brand LIKE '%Bud%' OR Brands.Brand LIKE '%Busch%'))
```

This is the Procedure I have come up so far.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductsBySearch]                               
        @idProduct     int          = NULL,   
        @sku          nvarchar(20) = NULL,              
        @breweryname    nvarchar(40) = NULL,                 
        @brand          nvarchar(40) = NULL,                 
        @country     nvarchar(15) = NULL,                 
        @prodname    nvarchar(40) = NULL,                 
        @searchStr    nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,                 
        --@PHRtbl     intlist_tbltype READONLY,
        @sortExpression      nvarchar(50) = NULL,
        @startRowIndex      int,
        @maximumRows      int,
        @idLocation     int = NULL,
        @idBrand        int = NULL,
        @strSearchType  nvarchar(5) = ' OR ',
        @debug       bit          = 0 

        AS                  

DECLARE @sql        nvarchar(MAX),                                 
        @paramlist  nvarchar(4000),                                
        @nl         char(2) = char(13) + char(10)

DECLARE @PHRtbl TABLE
(   PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    item NVARCHAR (MAX)
)       

IF @sortExpression IS NULL
    SET @sortExpression = 'sku'                          

INSERT INTO @PHRtbl
SELECT item FROM [dbo].[udf_List2Table](@searchStr,',')

DECLARE @i INT
SELECT @i = MIN(PK) FROM @PHRtbl
DECLARE @max INT
SELECT @max = MAX(PK) FROM @PHRtbl

DECLARE @SearchSQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @item AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
DECLARE @tmpSQL1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '
DECLARE @tmpSQL2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(Products.description LIKE '
DECLARE @tmpSQL3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(Products.Notes LIKE '
DECLARE @tmpSQL4 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(Products.SKU LIKE '
DECLARE @tmpSQL5 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '(Brands.Brand LIKE '


SELECT @sql =                                                      
    'SELECT SKU, productName, imgUrlThumb, Size, ProdType, CanType,
            CanManufacturer, breweryName, locName, CountryFlag, Brand
   FROM
      (SELECT  Products.SKU, Products.Description as productName, Products.imgUrlThumb, LookupSize.Size, ProdType.ProdType, CanTypes.Description AS CanType,
            CanManufacturer.CanManufacturer, brewery.breweryName, Locations.locName, Locations.CountryFlag, Brands.Brand, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') AS RowNum
       FROM Products INNER JOIN
         brewery ON Products.idBrewery = brewery.idBrewery INNER JOIN
         CanManufacturer ON Products.idCanManufacturer = CanManufacturer.idCanManufacturer INNER JOIN
         CanTypes ON Products.idCanType = CanTypes.idCanType INNER JOIN 
         Locations ON brewery.idLocation = Locations.idLocation INNER JOIN 
         LookupSize ON Products.idSize = LookupSize.idSize INNER JOIN
         ProdType ON Products.idProdType = ProdType.idProdtype INNER JOIN
         CatProd ON Products.idProduct = CatProd.idProduct INNER JOIN 
         Categories ON CatProd.idCategory = Categories.idCategory INNER JOIN 
         Brands ON Brands.idBrand = Products.idBrand 
         WHERE 1 = 1 '  + @nl

IF @searchStr IS NOT NULL   
    WHILE @i <= @max 
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @item = item FROM @PHRtbl WHERE PK = @i   
            IF (@i = @max) 
                BEGIN    
                    SET @tmpSQL1 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')' 
                    SET @tmpSQL2 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')'
                    SET @tmpSQL3 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')'
                    SET @tmpSQL4 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')'
                    SET @tmpSQL5 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')'
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SET @tmpSQL1 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')' + @strSearchType + ' Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL2 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')' + @strSearchType + ' Products.description LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL3 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')' + @strSearchType + ' Products.Notes LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL4 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')' + @strSearchType + ' Products.SKU LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL5 += ''%'' & @item + ''%')' + @strSearchType + ' Brands.Brand LIKE '
                END




            SELECT @item = NULL
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
   --moved this out of the while loop
   -- put it all together
        SET @SearchSQL = @SearchSQL + 'AND (' + @tmpSQL1 + ' OR ' + @tmpSQL2 + ' OR ' + @tmpSQL3 + ' OR ' + @tmpSQL4 + ' OR ' + @tmpSQL5 + ') ' + @nl
    -- Uncommend below to check the SQL
    PRINT @SearchSQL

   SELECT @sql += ' @SearchSQL' + @nl

IF @idProduct IS NOT NULL                                            
   SELECT @sql += ' AND Products.idProduct = @idProduct' + @nl               

IF @idBrand IS NOT NULL                                            
   SELECT @sql += ' AND Products.idBrand = @idBrand' + @nl               

IF @idLocation IS NOT NULL                                            
   SELECT @sql += ' AND Brewery.idLocation = @idLocation' + @nl               

  IF @brand IS NOT NULL                                           
   SELECT @sql += ' AND Brands.brand LIKE ''%'' + @brand + ''%'''  + @nl          

IF @breweryname IS NOT NULL                                           
   SELECT @sql += ' AND Brewery.breweryName LIKE ''%'' + @breweryname + ''%'''  + @nl          

IF @prodname IS NOT NULL                                            
   SELECT @sql += ' AND Products.Description LIKE ''%'' + @prodname + ''%''' + @nl

IF @searchStr IS NOT NULL                                        
   SELECT @sql += ' @searchStr' + @nl

SELECT @sql +=          ') AS myData
   WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + 
                ' - 1) * ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@MaximumRows) + ' AND (((' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' - 1) * ' 
                + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ' + 1) + ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ') - 1'     

--IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @PHRtbl)                             
--   SELECT @sql += ' AND o.EmployeeID IN (SELECT val FROM @employeetbl)' + @nl

--SELECT @sql += ' ORDER BY o.OrderID' + @nl                         

IF @debug = 1                                                      
   PRINT @sql                                                      

SELECT @paramlist = '@idProduct     int,   
                    @sku          nvarchar(20) ,              
                    @breweryname    nvarchar(40) ,                 
                    @brand          nvarchar(40) ,                 
                    @country     nvarchar(15) ,                 
                    @prodname    nvarchar(40) ,                 
                    @searchStr    nvarchar(MAX) ,                 
                    @PHRtbl   intlist_tbltype READONLY,
                    @sortExpression      nvarchar(50),
                    @startRowIndex      int,
                    @maximumRows      int,
                    @idLocation     int,
                    @idBrand        int,
                    @strSearchType  nvarchar(5)'



EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,                               
                 @idProduct,@sku,@breweryname,@brand,@country,@prodname,@searchStr,@PHRtbl,@sortExpression,
                 @startRowIndex,@maximumRows,@idLocation,@idBrand
```

Now when I try to execute the procedure I am getting the following errors. Due to the While loop to build the string. Know I have to figure out what is causing the error, and build the string and attach it @SQL that is being built.

**Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetProductsBySearch, Line 75
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator.
**

I was able to get the procedure to compile in the database by changing the quotes in this part.

```
                IF (@i = @max) 
                BEGIN    
                    SET @tmpSQL1 += '''%' + @item + '%'')' 
                    SET @tmpSQL2 += '''%' + @item + '%'')'
                    SET @tmpSQL3 += '''%' + @item + '%'')'
                    SET @tmpSQL4 += '''%' + @item + '%'')'
                    SET @tmpSQL5 += '''%' + @item + '%'')'
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SET @tmpSQL1 += '''%' + @item + '%'')' + @strSearchType + ' Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL2 += '''%' + @item + '%'')' + @strSearchType + ' Products.description LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL3 += '''%' + @item + '%'')' + @strSearchType + ' Products.Notes LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL4 += '''%' + @item + '%'')' + @strSearchType + ' Products.SKU LIKE '
                    SET @tmpSQL5 += '''%' + @item + '%'')' + @strSearchType + ' Brands.Brand LIKE '
                END
```

Now when I execute it I get this error.
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
Operand type clash: table is incompatible with nvarchar

I suspect the above section is the culprit. I have a Print Statement to Print the Strings as they are built, the error comes up first. Where or how do I see what the @SearchStr variable looks like?

I have extracted that section of code into a new window. With one value in the searchStr variable I get the the correct build of the searchSQL.

```
AND ((Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '%Bud%')
OR (Products.description LIKE '%Bud%')
OR (Products.Notes LIKE '%Bud%')
OR (Products.SKU LIKE '%Bud%')
OR (Brands.Brand LIKE '%Bud%')
)
```

However when I add another item to the list I get this:

```
AND ((Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Brewery.BreweryName LIKE 
OR (Products.description LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Products.description LIKE 
OR (Products.Notes LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Products.Notes LIKE 
OR (Products.SKU LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Products.SKU LIKE 
OR (Brands.Brand LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Brands.Brand LIKE 
)
```

I am almost there. Just need to figure what part of the string needs readjusting to get it right

```
AND ((Brewery.BreweryName LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Brewery.BreweryName LIKE 
'%Busch%')
OR (Products.description LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Products.description LIKE 
'%Busch%')
OR (Products.Notes LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Products.Notes LIKE 
'%Busch%')
OR (Products.SKU LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Products.SKU LIKE 
'%Busch%')
OR (Brands.Brand LIKE '%Bud%') OR  Brands.Brand LIKE 
'%Busch%')
)
```

Comment: I assume you want to use exiting code, thats why you are trying to debug the code, Am I right? If yes, then you can run the SQL profiler and get the query from that. When you run the SQL profiler it shows execution of queries. And you can take it from that.

Comment: You are wanting to pass "array like" collections as parameters to your stored proc, so the answer depends on what version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. I can pass the collections in to the procedure, and into the table type. But I am unsure how to loop thru the table type to build the sql string. I can build the string in the code behind, but I will get an error when I try to add it to the dynamic sql string.

Comment: @JBrooks I have added my procedure code that I have come up with so far. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The modulo character is `%`. The SQL you're building is building an expression that looks something like this `'astring'%'anotherstring'`, so instead of just running your enormous SQL, `PRINT` it out so you can debug and work out where you're getting the quotes wrong.

Comment: In short instead of `EXEC sp_executesql @sql`, run `PRINT @sql`. Paste the results and we can help debug.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I suspect the above section in the Loop is the culprit. I have a Print Statement to Print the SearchStr, however the error comes up first. Where or how do I see what the SearchStr variable looks like?

Comment: There are a few ways to debug: 1. Scatter `print` through the SP. 2. Learn how to debug stored procedures in SSMS. 3. Continue with your 'divide and conquer' method - I find this really effective - just keep shaving out bits of code until you find the offending code. Also just be aware that `print` prints to a different window in SSMS. The error looks to me like it doesn't like you passing in a table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have made a few changes and got the string looking closer to what it should be, not entirely sure of why the resulting string is not right when there is more than one item in the list

Comment: Just solved this. I removed the right side parentheses from string and that resolved. A few other script changes and I got this baby running. Thanks to all who offered advice

Comment: Good to hear! Well done for sticking with it